# Why can't I fav, heart, or like some songs on Beats 1 radio?

Tags: apple-music

The heart button isn't tappable sometimes while listening to Beats 1 radio on Apple Music. Why is that?

Comment: right now, probably because more than 10 million people are all trying it out at once ;)

Answer (score -1):

Well, since Music just came out a couple of hours ago, there is probably a lot of people checking it out and lagging the servers. It could also be that you have an older device and Apple hasn't optimized Apple Music for your device yet so its lagging. I had the same problem and I have the iPhone 4s.